# Select2, Typing in search input caused option:selected change its value

Tags: jquery-select2

Select2 is a great plugins, but i encounter serious problem with it

[image]

In the picture above, my option list has two option which is "KABUPATEN MOJOKERTO" and "KOTA MOJOKERTO"

In the picture above i tried to seach with the words "Mo", still no problem for me,

But when i type three characters or more like "Moj", the problems occurs, the selected option text change into what i type and the option "KABUPATEN MOJOKERTO" is missing, maybe hidden bellow selected option
This is the screenshot

[image]

What i want is no change in selected option text when i type in search input, so the option "KABUPATEN MOJOKERTO" is visible

I used Yii2 bootstrap 5

I have search my problem over web but no luck

I tried other version of select2, turns out this behavior started from version 4

Anybody can help please ?

Comment: Add your select2 related code in question. Looks like you have enabled tags option in select2, set tags to false in select2 config to avoid the behavior.

Comment: it still occurs, i think tags are related for creating a new option, not searching behavior
This behavior started on select2 version 4

Answer (score 0):

I just founded a solution

I edited select2.full.js, then search go to

```
this.$search.on('input', function (evt) {
    // Unbind the duplicated `keyup` event
    $(this).off('keyup');
});
```

then just comment/disabled keyup event like this

```
this.$search.on('input', function (evt) {
      // Unbind the duplicated `keyup` event
      // $(this).off('keyup');
});
```

so, the result as i wanted

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhyEV.jpg)

And in select2.full.min.js, find and remove

```
o(this).off("keyup")
```

This is for select2 4.0.13

Maybe anybody has a better solution ?